# Что делает данная функция?

Tags: c, c++

```
byte *buf = NULL;
int bufsize = 0;

int F(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    int i = *(const int *) l;
    int j = *(const int *) r;
    int ac = bufsize;

    while (buf[i] == buf[j]) {
        if (++i == bufsize)
            i = 0;
        if (++j == bufsize)
            j = 0;
        if (!--ac)
            return 0;
    }
    if (buf[i] > buf[j])
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: какой-то компаратор зацикленного масива, физический смысл его понять без вызывающего алгоритма сложно.

Comment: Где здесь C++?

Comment: @igumnov, большинство Си программ являются и С++ программами. По крайней мере с точки зрения компилятора.

К этой достаточно приписать

    #include <iostream>

Comment: да, этот код как-то связан с сортировкой данных.
но вот, что он возвращает? и что делает с данными?
нужно простое обьяснение, как в справочнике или мануале.

мне кажется, пользователь "avp" что-то нащупал, во 2 варианте.

Comment: @Вячеслав1101, Что Вам непонятно из моего ответа?

Вам **действительно нужно** "как в мануале"?

Answer (score 5):

- Это *не самый удачный* код для сравнения содержимого буфера с учетом его циклических сдвигов. В оригинале функция называется [`rotlexcmp`,](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Преобразование_Барроуза_—_Уилера) и, в общем-то, делает то, что заявлено в названии.

> В похожем виде, кстати говоря, эта функция присутствует в исходном коде [`X11-Basic`.](http://fossies.org/dox/X11Basic-1.19/decode_8c_source.html)

- Спрямить этот код для большей понятности можно было бы примерно следующим образом:

  ```
  int compare_rotated_buffer(
      const char* buffer, int buffer_size,
      int first_rotation_start, int second_rotation_start)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i)
      {
          const char a =
              buffer[(first_rotation_start + i) % buffer_size];
          const char b =
              buffer[(second_rotation_start + i) % buffer_size];

          if (a > b)
              return 1;
          else if (a < b)
              return -1;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: @Котик, здорово! Как Вы это все находите? 

Просто энциклопедические познания.

Comment: @avp, интернет длинный и широкий...

Comment: @Аsen, ну да. Вот только, в этом случае, нужно четко знать что ищешь.

Comment: нагуглил все таки. все потому, что я обленился. и чуть-чуть не доглядел.

а я ведь специально, изменил имена основных переменных и функций,
чтоб сразу отсеять, любителей погуглить.
оставив, только людей с мозгами.

Comment: @KiTE, ну да =)

Comment: @Вячеслав1101, нагуглил или нет ответит только @Котик_хочет_кушать. Чтобы отвечать на такие вопросы нужно хотя бы раз с этой функцией  столкнуться.

И, какая разница откуда инфа, если человек дал четкий и понятный ответ на вопрос. Или это вопрос ради вопроса?

Comment: @Вячеслав1101

- Ну, вообще, я сначала переписал эту функцию, а только потом полез искать, зачем автору понадобилось пихать `int'ы` через `const void *`.

- И, зачем, кстати говоря, вы решили провести спортивное состязание между участниками ХэшКода (раз вы уже знали ответ на свой вопрос)?

Comment: зачем? чтоб получить действительно понятное обьяснение,
а не банальный, лишенный смысла, копипаст из Википедии.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже она лексикографически сравнивает бесконечные (или длины bufsize, что эквивалентно) последовательности в зацикленном буфере buf.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно перед вызовом `buf` и `bufsize` должны быть правильно инициированы.

***Далее необоснованные соображения*** (это был *вариант 1*)

Похоже на лексикографическое сравнение (как указал [[@dzhioev](/users/552/dzhioev)](/users/552/dzhioev)) в циклическом буфере для **2-х** "строк" (видимо нулем они не должны заканчиваться), каждая длиной в половину буфера.
  В `l` передается адрес индекса `buf`, в котором начинается первая строка, в `r` вторая.

Возвращается результат, похожий на результат `str(n)cmp`.  
   0 - если строки равны (отсюда предположение о размере строк), а вместо разницы кодов неравных символов (результата `str(n)cmp) возвращаются -1 (первая строка меньше) или 1 (первая больше).

Для чего на практике может применяться данная функция - не знаю.

***Новые соображения*** (*вариант 2*)

Это функция часть поиска повторяющихся последовательностей вида **`aaa...`** или  **`ababab...`** или **`abcdabcdabcd...`** и т.д., использующая циклический буфер.

К сожалению код заполнения буфера и циклы переборов `*l` и `*r` отсутствуют.
Вот и проклюнулся практический смысл.

Comment: Откуда инфа про "длиной в половину буфера"?

Comment: Неправильное соображение. Только что дошло. Сейчас исправляю.

Comment: l r это скорее всего левая и правая граница подстроки внутри буфера, включения которой в остальной буфер и проверяются. Ноль возвращается если подстрока больше половины буфера. 1 совпадение -1 нет совпадений. Хотя я не до конца уверен, весьма хитроумный код

Comment: @igumnov Это обычный компаратор, поэтому для совпадения возвращается `0`, а для разных лексикографических порядков - `1` и `-1` соответственно.

Answer (score -6):

Это очень похоже на алгоритм быстрой сортировки некого буфера `buf` размером `bufsize.`

Comment: Абсолютно ничего общего.

Comment: @Аsen, под словами "алгоритм быстрой сортировки" Вы, видимо, подразумевали функцию сравнения (компаратор), передаваемую в qsort()?

Если да, то выражайтесь яснее. Обычно *алгоритмом* быстрой сортировки называют то, чему передается этот компаратор.

Comment: @avp, ну да, "Comparetor". =)

Comment: avp, это ссылка не на того Asen'а.

Comment: @GLmonster, а я их не особо различаю.

Comment: Я так понимаю, тут на клонов не обращают внимания?

Comment: @GLmonster, Вы имеете в виду, что *этот* "Asen" и забаненый некоторое время назад "Asen" это разные люди?

Или какое-то физическое лицо присутствует здесь под разными никами?

Ну и что?

Comment: Один человек, зарегистрированный под одним ником 2 раза.